# WordPress if-menu condition

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements

I am using https://wordpress.org/plugins/if-menu/ to create a condition to show a parent and sub pages on certain pages.

```
add_filter( 'if_menu_conditions', 'my_new_menu_condition' );

function my_new_menu_condition( $conditions ) {

global $post;

$conditions[] = array(
    'name'    =>  'Condition Name', // name of the condition
    'condition' =>  function($item) {          // callback - must return TRUE or FALSE
      return is_page('Parent Page' ) || is_page('Parent Page' ) && $post->post_parent > 0;
    }
  );

  return $conditions;
}
```

I am not having much luck. Does anyone have any experience with this plugin and know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: From the condition it's hard to tell what you are trying to check? It's always evaluating a page called 'Parent Page'. What is the condition you are intending. Because it appears that that is where the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a several pages that represent city names. Each one of those city names have community sub pages. I would like to display city in the nav to only show on their corresponding pages. I have it showing on the parent currently without issue but when you go to a subpage the parent link does not display in the navigation. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that comes across this. Here is what worked for me.

Add this to your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'if_menu_conditions', 'my_new_menu_condition' );


function my_new_menu_condition( $conditions ) {
  $conditions[] = array(
    'name'    =>  'insertpagename', // name of the condition
    'condition' =>  function(){
        global $post;
        $pages = get_pages(); 
        $post_parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
        foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
            if ( is_page('insertpagename') || $post_parent->post_name == 'insertpagename' ) { 
                return is_page();
            }
        }
      }
  );

  $conditions[] = array(
        'name'    =>  'insertpagename2', // name of the condition
        'condition' =>  function(){
            global $post;
            $pages = get_pages(); 
            $post_parent = get_post($post->post_parent);
            foreach ( $pages as $page ) {
                if ( is_page('insertpagename2') || $post_parent->post_name == 'insertpagename2' ) { 
                    return is_page();
                }
            }
          }
  );
  return $conditions;
}
```